# Are variables stored again in RAM?

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu, memory-hardware, memory-allocation

Assuming this set of instructions:

1. declare variable 'A' which has value 5
2. declare variable 'B' which has value 2

From what I've understood, those instructions are loaded into RAM an then read by CPU, they are composed by OPCODE + Data. So, lets assume that the opcode to set a value for a specific RAM address is (0001). First instruction is in binary 0001 (opcode) + value (0b101) and the second is 0001 (opcode) + 0b10 (value). Are this values moved in a different memory area where process data will reside?

Hopefully what I asked makes sense, Sorry for the dumb question, I just started to learn CS.

Comment: The instructions do not just include the value, but also the address, if there is one. The CPU doesn't know about variables - the compiler has to choose an address for each variable.

Answer (score 1):

There is no unique answer, that can depend on code optimizations.

If the data that you are considering is constant, it could be used in *immediate* mode, i.e. be inserted in the instruction flow where needed. E.g.

```
Load R0, 5
Load R1, 2
Add R0, R1
...
```

The immediate value would have to be repeated everywhere the variable is used. The variable is never assigned a location in RAM, it just transits through registers.

Another possibility is to have the variable stored in some RAM location, by means of an address. Now it is the address which is used inside the flow of instructions:

```
Load R0, (A)
Load R1, (B)
Add R0, R1
...
```

where (A) could be an explicit memory address such as 0x5F3B0001, and the load is made from this address.

The value contained in the variable can be computed and stored during program execution. If the initial value is known at compile-time, it can also be encoded in the executable file and copied to RAM when the program is loaded.

In some cases, the variables are assigned an address permanently (i.e. throughout program execution). In other cases, for variables with a shorter lifetime, this is done dynamically, for example using a slot in the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. Depending on the instruction addressing mode, you may have the data stored in the instruction itself(immediate), no data(implicit), in some register(register), or at a memory location(direct/indirect). There are much more addressing modes available which combine one or more of such addressing modes.

Are these values moved to some different location? If you move the values your program wouldn't be valid anymore(for arguments sake). Yet, it is done by using addressing modes that allow for code relocation. The process data is much more than instructions and data, which is managed by the operating system.